# Connection refused when trying to connect to RabbitMQ docker container from Java docker container

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I have a Java container which has to fetch messages from a RabbitMQ container. This is the code I am using in order to connect to it (I have:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("rabbit2");
    factory.setPort(5673);
    factory.setUsername("guest");
    factory.setPassword("guest");

    log.info("Got here!");

    Connection connection = null;

    try {
      connection = factory.newConnection("Connection1");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
      throw e;
    }
```

This is the library I am using:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

The hostname of the rabbitmq container was configured to be rabbit2. I am using docker compose.
This is the config for the rabbit mq instance:

```
output_mb:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    hostname: rabbit2
    container_name: output_mb
    ports:
        - 5673:5672
        - 15673:15672
    volumes:
        - "./output_mb/rabbitmq.config:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config"
        - "./output_mb/definitions.json:/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json"
    networks:
        - common_network
```

And this is the config for the java instance:

```
pollution_dashboard:
    container_name: pollution_dashboard
    image: pollution_dashboard:latest
    restart: on-failure
    hostname: pollution_dashboard
    depends_on:
        - input_mb
        - output_mb
    ports:
        - 8080:8080
    build:
        context: ./pollution_dashboard/pollution_dashboard
        dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    networks:
        - common_network
```

However, I keep getting **Connection refused** in my java service when I run my docker compose. There are other services in the stack as well that do not have issues communicating with the rabbitmq instance. (They are using other languages)

What could be the problem?

Comment: "factory.setPort(5673);" you sure that's the correct port?  [Normally](https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html) it would be 5672 but you can configure rabbit to listen on something else.  make sure they both match. Connection refused means you could reach the server but it's not listening on that port

Comment: To communicate between docker containers, you use the original port of the image, not the rebound port, that is you need to use port 5672, not 5673.